# Swift cocoapod install framework (Alamofire) occur Syntax error in xcode

Tags: xcode, swift, cocoapods, alamofire

I have some problem in installing some external framework. Therefore, I try it in a blank project but the error are the same and I am not sure where i did wrong.[error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CDy7P.png)

It is a little uncommon. It seems like I did install a wrong version of framework as in it appear 40+ error in code syntax.
Also, the error are from Alamofire,AmazonS3RequestManager and so on.
It is my podfile and I just put `pod install` in the target file directory

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
# Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
platform :ios, '8.0'
# Uncomment this line if you're using Swift
use_frameworks!

target 'test' do
pod 'FBSDKCoreKit'
pod 'FBSDKLoginKit'
pod 'FBSDKShareKit'
pod 'AlamofireImage', '~> 2.0'
pod 'Firebase', '>= 2.4.3'
pod 'SwiftValidator', '3.0.1'
pod 'AmazonS3RequestManager', '~> 0.8'
pod 'MBProgressHUD', '~> 0.9.2'

end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code in your screenshot is for Swift 2.2, so you have to update Xcode to the latest version, Xcode 7.3. Your version is too old.

Comment: i just checked my xcode version is 7.2. In this case, how can i fix this without updating the latest version?

Comment: Well, if you can't upgrade Xcode, you'll have to downgrade the libraries. Set version numbers in the Podfile that correspond to a version acceptable by Xcode 7.2 - but I would suggest you actually update Xcode instead.